# Why isn't a function tail recursive?

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

I'm reading Programming in Scala by M. Odersky and he says that

> Functions like approximate, which call themselves as their last
>   action, are called tail recursive.

So, I tried this:

```
object Main extends App {
    implicit val mc = new MyClass(8)
    val ti = new TestImplct
    ti.test
}

class TestImplct {
  def test(implicit mc : MyClass): Unit = {
    println(mc.i)
    mc.i -= 1
    if(mc.i < 0){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException
    }
    test
  }
}

class MyClass(var i : Int)
```

[***IDEONE DEMO***](http://ideone.com/mMkj5S)

But it generates the following stack trace

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at TestImplct.test(Main.scala:13)
    at TestImplct.test(Main.scala:15)
    at TestImplct.test(Main.scala:15)
    at TestImplct.test(Main.scala:15)
    at TestImplct.test(Main.scala:15)
    at TestImplct.test(Main.scala:15)
    at TestImplct.test(Main.scala:15)
    at TestImplct.test(Main.scala:15)
    at TestImplct.test(Main.scala:15)
```

Which means that it generates a new stack frame for each recursive call. But the last action is to call to itself. What's wrong and how to make it tail-recursive?

Why doesn't compiler do tail-call optimization?

Comment: Do you have an implicit instance of MyClass in scope?

Comment: @Samar Yes, I have. Look at the demo

Comment: I see you have defined the class. But I dont see where you instantiated it.

Comment: @Samar Ah, you're right. i didn;t attach the full code. My appologies.

Comment: Its working fine. Why do you think its not tail recursive? Its just exiting because of the if condition.

Comment: @Samar I think so because compiler does not perform tail-call optimization.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try marking the method with `@tailrec` annotation. If you do that, compilation will fail and will show you why compiler couldn't optimize this to be tail recursive:

> Main.scala:12: error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method test: it is neither private nor final so can be overridden

Indeed, if you make the method `final`, it works as expected.

Comment: Interesting. Why does making the method final allow TCO here?

Comment: @Samar + 1 Also would like to know.

Comment: As the error says: otherwise method might be overridden by some implementation that isn't tail recursive, then you might think you're looking at a tail recursion when in fact not all calls would be able to make this optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works correctly. Your value in the `mc` object decrease with every step. At the last step you get the exception.

You can change the return type of your function to be `Boolean` for example and return `false` when your value is `< 0` otherwise you return `true`.

I would suggest, you use '@tailrec' annotation in order to get checked the recursive function call by compiler.